# SQL Subselect count and group

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need to pull all days in month, count and group them by the weekday. Below are sample of database:

```
id | uID | dateTime
0  | 01  | Monday
1  | 01  | Monday
2  | 01  | Monday
3  | 01  | Tuesday
4  | 01  | Tuseday
5  | 01  | Friday
```

Here are the array results that I want to retrieve from SQL:

```
id=>0 uID=>01 dateTime=>Monday  day_group=>3
id=>1 uID=>01 dateTime=>Monday  day_group=>0
id=>2 uID=>01 dateTime=>Monday  day_group=>0
id=>3 uID=>01 dateTime=>Tuesday day_group=>2
id=>4 uID=>01 dateTime=>Tuesday day_group=>0
id=>5 uID=>01 dateTime=>Friday  day_group=>1
```

And here are one of my attempts to do that:

```
SELECT 
id, 
uID, 
dateTime
FROM database,
  (SELECT 
  COUNT(id) AS day_group,
  uID,
  dateTime
  WHERE uID=:uID AND MONTH(:month)
  GROUP BY DAY(dateTime)
  FROM database)
WHERE uID=:uID AND MONTH(:month)
```

Comment: why a nested select?

Comment: if I don't do that, it will output just three day_group results = 3,2,1 and not all days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use window functions:

```
set @uID = 1;
set @month = 7;
select
   id, uID, datetim
   , COUNT(*) over (partition by DAY(dateTim)) AS day_group
from test
where uID=@uID and month(datetim) = @month
```

Or if you're using mysql older then 8.0, here is the sub-query equivalent:

```
set @uID = 1;
set @month = 7;
select
   t1.id, t1.uid, t1.datetim
   , coalesce(sq.day_group, 0)
from test as t1
    left outer join (select min(id) id, count(id) day_group from test as t2 where t2.uID=@uID and month(t2.datetim) = @month group by day(t2.datetim)) as sq on sq.id = t1.id
where t1.uID=@uID and month(t1.datetim) = @month
```

And the structure agains which I tested:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT auto_increment, uid int, datetim datetime, primary key(id));
INSERT INTO test (uid, datetim) VALUES (1, '2019-07-01');
INSERT INTO test (uid, datetim) VALUES (1, '2019-07-01');
INSERT INTO test (uid, datetim) VALUES (1, '2019-07-01');
INSERT INTO test (uid, datetim) VALUES (1, '2019-07-02');
INSERT INTO test (uid, datetim) VALUES (1, '2019-07-02');
INSERT INTO test (uid, datetim) VALUES (1, '2019-07-05');
```

And the fiddle where it can be tested: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=hpaL4iC26J)

Comment: Can you post here the error you received? For clarification, what language are you using?

Comment: I'm using MYSQL, the error is PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by DAY(dateTime)) AS day_group,

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? As I know, the window function is supported by most versions, but can't test the syntax by myself. Try replacing the * with id. For more information about window function pls see [Window Function Concepts and Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

Comment: I was using 5.7.19 then upgraded to 8.0.19 on wamp, still get same error. Also tried replacing * with id with no success.

Comment: I made an edit for the answer, corrected the syntax  error, added a sub-query equivalent. Also a link to an SQL Fiddle where I did my test

Comment: oh, cool, this works in 5.7.19 guess I will use that version, although it's longer, my server uses mysql 5.7.. is it possible to set day_group to 0 for next repeating days, as I wrote on needed result? day_group=>3 for first day, day_group=>0 for next repeating days

Comment: @Atis, I hope that by first, you meant by the smallest ID. If so, I made an edit to the second query

Comment: exactly! first occurrence is smallest id of that day, genius! Thank you!!